# Passing an instance of a class as an argument to the action/method of Url.Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, url-routing

My goal is to achieve the following:

1. While on an ASP.NET page, the user selects a server from a list of `Server` objects.
2. The user clicks a button to export information about that server.
3. Clicking the button executes a C# method `ExportServerInfo()` with the current `Server` object (`Model.Servers[i]`) passed to it.

The controller has the method:

```cs
public void ExportServerInfo(Server id)
{
    // Do something with the Server
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(id.Name);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(id.RamCapacity);
}
```

The view is a CSHTML file using Razor. This is the code for the button:

```html
<div class="col-md-12" align="right">
    <a href="@Url.Action("ExportServerInfo", "ServerList", new { id = Model.Servers[i] })" class="btn btn-primary">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         @MainResource.SomeLocalizationString
    </a>
</div>
```

HTML generated: `<a href="/ServerList/ExportServerInfo/ProjectName.ViewModels.Server" class=...>`

When the button is clicked, the method `ExportServerInfo()` in the ServerListController class should be called with the selected `Server` as the only argument. Instead, the user is brought to `localhost:56789/ServerList/ExportServerInfo/ProjectName.ViewModels.Server` with an HTTP 404 error from the web server because it can't find it; that string alone doesn't indicate which server it is. The method isn't called at all. A similar solution I tried brought the user to a blank page with the above as a query string in the URL instead.

When the user clicks the button, the method should be called, but instead, the user gets moved to a page (which 404s) and the method isn't called.

---

The method is executed if the action has no argument/parameter:

```html
<div class="col-md-12" align="right">
    <a href="@Url.Action("ExportServerInfo", "ServerList")" class="btn btn-primary">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         @MainResource.SomeLocalizationString
    </a>
</div>
```

HTML generated: `<a href="/ServerList/ExportServerInfo" class=...>`

The user clicks the button ("visiting" `/ServerList/ExportServerInfo`) but stays on the page, and the method runs (with no parameters). But the method must have a parameter to pass the `Server` back to the controller.

---

Also, for some reason, the look of the button is fine when it works, but the highlight colours are a little off with the wrong implementation.

**tl;dr:** Argument isn't passed to the method, method never runs, user is routed to 404 page. Method needs a `Server` passed into it.

Comment: @RyanWilson Oops! Fixed.

Comment: looks like your `Url.Action` needs updated. You have an `id` parameter but you are passing the whole model instead of just an id. Maybe try this: `@Url.Action("ExportServerInfo", "ServerList", new { id = Model.Servers[i].Id })`

Comment: The entire `Server` should be passed because ExportServerInfo has to read.  Server doesn't have an `id` variable; I think that's just the default one for routing. Not sure what you're supposed to do if you have multiple arguments, but nothing happens otherwise; I tried passing it as `new { server = Model.Servers[i] })` and making the method `ExportServerInfo (Server server)`.

Comment: ya that won't work like that. If you are just wanting to pass `Name` and `RamCapacity` then pass those has parameters like this: `@Url.Action("ExportServerInfo", "ServerList", new { name = Model.Servers[i].Name, ram =Model.Servers[i].RamCapacity  })` then update your action to accept those parameters: `public void ExportServerInfo(string name, string ram)`. It would only work that way if you were posting form values, then the MVC model binder would map the posted values to your `Server` model.

Comment: Ahhh; I feared as much. That worked; thanks. The button CSS is still a little off with this implementation for some reason, but it works. Feel free to submit it as answer!

Comment: @ErikHumphrey Another option would be to serialize the object and pass it to your controller as a JSON string then deserialize it in the controller into a Server class object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object cannot be passed directly from the view to the controller. If you only have a few properties that need to be passed, pass those as arguments in the type declarator.

If you must pass the entire object, [serialize the object](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm) and pass it as a string argument.

```
<div class="col-md-12" align="right">
    <a href="@Url.Action("ExportServerInfo", "ServerList", new { s = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Servers[i] })" class="btn btn-primary">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         @MainResource.SomeLocalizationString
    </a>
</div>
```

Adjust the method so that it takes in a string, then deserialize it and store it in a variable of the object's original type.

```
public void ExportServerInfo(string s)
{
    Server server = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Server>(s);

    // Do something with the Server
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(server.Name);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(server.RamCapacity);
}
```